# Button click never triggered on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, button, click

I have just published first beta of a word solving app (wordfeud in spanish) and am having some issues on the iPad, hope someone can help:

HTML

```
<button type="button" id='btnsolve'>Solve</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#btnsolve').click(function () {
  solvegame();
});
```

The `solvegame` function is never triggered on iPad but works on IE, FF and Chrome for windows.

The app is currently hosted at appharbor [can be seen here](http://xylophoneclient.apphb.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your page I can see that you commented out the jQuery's document ready event listening. Try to include (for now just) this jQuery code in a document ready listener and see whether it works on iPad.